# Complex systems of spatial vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, vector

I want to learn how to build complex systems of spatial vectors in tikZ/PGF (i do not know how to do this, because a beginner). As an example, i use the figure on the right. 
[image]
 did not find the most similar examples, and those that remotely resemble such a picture are too complicated for a beginner. How to build, for example, a vector e3 and x with a given angle between them, connect their ends with a red dashed line, create an angle designation (an arc between the vectors) and designate it with some Greek letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These things are fairly simple to obtain. You can install your own coordinate system, and use it to draw these vectors and objects. I recommend starting from an orthogonal system and then changing some basis vectors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-20} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
 pics/axis/.style={code={
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_2$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_3$};
 }}]
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,z={(0,0.3,1)},thick]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{b}};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,1.2,3) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \draw[dashed] (3,0,0) -- (3,1.2,0) -- (0,1.2,0) 
  (3,1.2,0) -- (3,1.2,3) -- (0,0,3);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,x={(1,-0.3,0)},thick,red]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{e}};
  \draw[->,black] (0,0,0) -- (3,3,3) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \draw[dashed] (3,0,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (0,3,0) 
  (3,3,0) -- (3,3,3) -- (0,0,3) -- (3,0,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (0,3,3) -- (0,0,3)
  (3,0,3) -- (3,0,0) (0,3,3) -- (0,3,0);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,y={(-0.3,1,0)},z={(0.21,-0.3,1)},thick,blue]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{u}};
  \draw[->,black] (0,0,0) -- (3,3,3) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \draw[dashed] (3,0,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (0,3,0) 
  (3,3,0) -- (3,3,3) -- (0,0,3) -- (3,0,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (0,3,3) -- (0,0,3)
  (3,0,3) -- (3,0,0) (0,3,3) -- (0,3,0);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to be able to compute the projections of some vector on the coordinates with Ti*k*Z, you may be interested in the **experimental** [`3dtools` library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools). You'd need to download [`tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex`](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex) somewhere where LaTeX can find it (such as the same directory as the file that you compile). The library's [manual](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/3DToolsManual.pdf) gives you some idea what you can use it for.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
 pics/axis/.style={code={
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_2$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.1] {$#1_3$};
 }},
 pics/projections/.style={code={
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{TD("(1,0,0)o#1")}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{TD("(0,1,0)o#1")}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myz}{TD("(0,0,1)o#1")}
 \draw[pic actions] #1 -- (\myx,\myy,0)  -- (0,\myy,0)
  (\myx,\myy,0)  -- (\myx,0,0) -- (\myx,0,\myz)
   (0,\myy,0) --  (0,\myy,\myz)
  #1 -- (\myx,0,\myz) -- (0,0,\myz) -- (0,\myy,\myz) -- #1;
 }},3d/install view={phi=-20,psi=0,theta=110}]
 \begin{scope}[z={(0,0.3,1)},thick]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{b}};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,1.2,3) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \draw[dashed] (3,0,0) -- (3,1.2,0) -- (0,1.2,0) 
  (3,1.2,0) -- (3,1.2,3) -- (0,0,3);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,x={(1,-0.3,0)},thick,red]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{e}};
  \draw[->,black] (0,0,0) -- (3,3,3) coordinate (x) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \pic[dashed] {projections=(x)};
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,y={(-0.3,1,0)},z={(0.21,-0.3,1)},thick,blue]
  \pic{axis=\mathbf{u}};
  \draw[->,black] (0,0,0) -- (3,3,3) coordinate (x') node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
  \pic[dashed] {projections=(x')};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Schrödinger's cat, thank you! It's very helpful!